# How to split the values of any given table column into new rows at delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code splits the values in a one column table into new rows at the slash delimiter.
I does not work however on a multiple column table.
Sometimes I need to split the values of the third column.

The desired outcome would be something like this if applied on the third column.
 For each occurrence of the delimiter a new row is created.
 the values in below table are just as example, real values are not always 1 character long.
[image]

```js
$('#tbl tr').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var arr = $this.text().split('/');
  var firstTwo = arr.splice(0, 2);
  var firstEl = firstTwo.join('/').trim();
  arr.unshift(firstEl);
  var len = arr.length;
  var i;
  var $previous = $this;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var $tr = $this.clone();
    $tr.find("td").text(arr[i]);
    $previous.after($tr);
    $previous = $tr;
  }
  $this.remove();
});
```

```css
th {
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

td {
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tbl-header">
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A/B/C</td>
      <td>B/C</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A/B</td>
      <td>B/C</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>D/E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A/B/C/D</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>C/D/E</td>
      <td>D/E/F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>B/C/D</td>
      <td>C/D</td>
      <td>D/E/F/G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A/B/C</td>
      <td>B/C/D/E</td>
      <td>C/D/E</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help...

```
        <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#tbl tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            var arr = $this.text().split('/');
            var $previous = $this.parent();

            //console.log($previous);
            //console.log(arr.length);
            if(arr.length >1){            

                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
                  var $tr = $previous.clone();             

                  $previous.after($tr);
                  var yourCell = $previous.find('td:nth-child(3)');
                  //console.log(yourCell.text());
                  yourCell.text(arr[i]);

                  $previous = $tr;
                }

                $previous.remove();
            }

          });

       });
    </script>
```